# Using SED to Get the Last n Lines of a Huge Text File

Tags: linux, text, sed

How can I use "sed" command to get the last n lines of a huge text file (e.g. A.txt) and copy them into a new text file(e.g. B.txt)? I do not want to remove that lines from A.txt.

Comment: isn't `tail -n 42` a perfect fit (for `n`==42)?

Comment: @sehe That's what I said... (Wanna parse some HTML using `sed` instead?)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You don't. You use `tail -n NUMLINES` for that.

```
tail -n 100 A.txt > B.txt
```

Answer (score 16):

Here's how to use sed to print the last 10 lines of a file:

```
sed -e :a -e '$q;N;11,$D;ba'
```

You should probably only use this if you're planning on executing more sed commands on these lines. Otherwise the `tail` command is designed for this job.

Comment: Not sure of impressive or impertinent :)

Comment: I don't have tail on my computer, only sed, awk and some others.

Comment: This answer surely works! But, for me at least, I always appreciate an explanation of what all the `sed` operators do :)

Comment: I just realized GNU's `sed` has a `--debug` flag that's very helpful.

Answer (score 13):

Using GNU sed, here's how to get the last 10 lines:

*(For n lines, replace 11, with n+1)*

`sed -ne':a;$p;N;11,$D;ba' A.txt > B.txt`

**Note**: On my Mac, with MacPorts, GNU sed is invoked as `gsed`. To use Apple's `sed` you would have to separate the label: `sed -ne':a' -e'$p;N;11,$D;ba'`*

#### Explanation:

`sed -ne'` invoke sed without automatic printing pattern space

`:a` label for looping

`$p` on last line, print pattern space, then quit

`N` slurp the next line

`11,$D` on line 11 through last line, remove the first line from pattern space (i.e. [^\n]*\n)

`ba'` loop to `:a`

#### Further

Because of the loop, `sed` continuously appends the next line to pattern space. After line 11 and through the last line (`11,$D`) `sed` begins removing the first line from pattern space. At the last line the pattern space is printed (`$p'), which contains the last 10 most recently slurped lines (the last 10 lines of file A.txt).